# Find pipe at the beginning of each line

Tags: database, csv, pipe, notepad++

Using Notepad++ (v7.8.1). I have a 2 million+ row text/csv file that is pipe separated. The first field is an ID number. I'm told that there are 1400 lines without an ID number. I need to find these lines. The best way I can think of is to find those lines with a pipe as the first character. I just cannot figure out how to search only the first character of each line. I need it to ignore the 30 million other pipes in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try doing a search for `^\s*\|`, which would highlight any line which starts either with a pipe, or possibly some amount of whitespace followed first by a pipe.

### Demo

Comment: All 3 of these comments are basically the same, and are all useful. Thank you!

Comment: It's Pepsi!Thanks, I forgot about the check mark. Literally my first question here.

Answer (score 0):

turn on Regular expression searching at the bottom of the search window and search for `^\|`

`^` - start of line

`\|` - an escaped pipe

Comment: A more simple solution to the problem. Very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions. `^\|`

^ == beginning of a line

\ == escape character

| == match the pipe.

https://regex101.com/r/rIlZ5C/1

Comment: Your comment actually taught me the reason it worked! Thank you!